# HSQLDB - pre-9.0 client attemtped to connect

Tags: java, ant, hsqldb

Trying to get production application to work with hsqldb.  The application is built with ant and the compile.classpath is set with hsqldb.jar and the application is executed with hsqldb.jar in the classpath.  All versions of the jar file are the same and up to date, however, I'm getting a "pre-9.0 client attemtped to connect. We rejected them." error from the database linux terminal.

I've created a test app where I can create the same error if I make the jar without hsqldb.jar as an external jar file in eclipse.  (If i include the jar it works perfectly)

I thought I could run the test app by specifying the hsqldb.jar cp at run time.  Should this not be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this discussion:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/forums/forum/73674/topic/3825892

Comment: To the best of my knowledge I'm the first person to load hsqldb onto our system and only v2.0.0 so I don't think its the old version jar file laying around syndrome.

If it ends up being such, I'll be glad to admit it.

Comment: I'm also using hibernate with a C3P0 connection pool.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget that some applications bundle HSQLDB with them, e.g. OpenOffice

Comment: Moved hsqldb.jar to first declared in classpath and program crashed further along for other reasons after where I was getting the "pre-9.0 client attempt" error.

This is progress.